# Arduino Nano and ESP32 Read Different Values over Serial

Tags: serial, esp32, uart

I am trying to use the [Neato xv11 lidar](https://web.archive.org/web/20160513114247/http://xv11hacking.wikispaces.com/LIDAR+Sensor) with an ESP32. This should output packets of 22 bytes with the starting byte 0xFA. The communication is 8N1 and the baud rate is 115200.

When I connect the Lidar TX to the ESP32 RX2 pin, I get data that does not make sense as I get the start byte every 9 (and sometimes 8) bytes. However, when I run the same code on an Arduino Nano, I get the correct 22 byte packages. I even connected both at once and logged the results in Putty. This is the data I got.

```c
// Arduino Nano Code
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
}
void loop() {
  while (Serial1.available()) {
    Serial.println(Serial1.read(),HEX);
  }
}
```

```cpp
// ESP32 Code
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    Serial.println(Serial2.read(),HEX);
  }
}
```

ESP32

```
FA
A8
0
35
6D
11
17
71
3D
FA
A9
0
3D
12
97
12
10
D1
41
FA
AA
0
E1
E
14
12
E7
1F
FA
AB
```

Arduino Nano

```
FA
D8
74
35
6B
3
3D
1
7B
3
3B
1
8C
3
2B
1
9F
3
1C
1
A
1D
FA
D9
74
35
B2
3
```

Comment: try running Serial at a higher baud rate ... also try using `if`, instead of `while`

Comment: did you check the voltage of the communication?

Comment: I checked the voltage and tried voltage converters. The ESP32 still gets strange data. I also tried to use an if statement instead of while and that did not fix it. It is very strange behaviour.